# React: How can you pass all the state at once to the child component with Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

With class components, when you have a lot of state to pass down, instead of passing down ten state objects one by one, I saw that you can do something like this:

```
<Childcomponent {...this.state}/>
```

or

```
<Childcomponent data={this.state}/>
```

Do you know how to do the same if you UseState or UseReducer?

I looked all over and I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

By the way, since React itself recommends not to use the Context API too much, I am trying to find out if you can do this without it.

Comment: Why not using props when you're using functional components?

Answer (score 2):

If you have all the state in one useState hook then just pass that down to child component

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

<Childcomponent data={data}/>
```

If you have multiple useState hooks in your component and you want to pass all the state down to child component

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const [data2, setData2] = useState({});
const [data3, setData3] = useState({});

<Childcomponent data={{ ...data, ...data2, ...data3 }}/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Would you mind showing me an example of how I should receive the data on the child component?

Comment: In `Childcomponent`, all the state you passed from parent component will be available on `props.data` object.

Answer (score 0):

yah you can follow , for class based component

```
<child {...this.state}/>
```

this below approach also helpful

```
 <child data={this.state}/>
```

both options you mentioned is ok. in second approach all of your state will be under **data** . You can get them **props.data.something** in your child component.

also for hooks

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
name: 'Lorem',
email: 'lorem@gmail.com',
});

 <child  data ={state} />
```

You can have also another option you can follow, state management with Redux.It has huge advantage too.

Comment: I started with React not long ago, so I haven't learnt Redux. However, at this point in time I think I'd rather learn Recoil. It look really promising.

Comment: Sure , its up to you, there is many ways to handle state. Recoil is new, you can follow that too.